# Plotly slider not responding

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to animate a plotly 3D scatter figure and the slider is not responding (see code below).
Has anybody got a clue what how to solve the issue?

Thanks and best wishes!
Christian

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# Define the initial plot
x = MC1Array[0,:,0]
y = MC1Array[0,:,1]
z = MC1Array[0,:,2]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', marker=dict(size=2))])

# Add frames to the plot
frames = []
for t in range(np.shape(MC1Array[:,:,0])[0]):
    x = MC1Array[t,:,0]
    y = MC1Array[t,:,1]
    z = MC1Array[t,:,2]
    frame = go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', name=f'{t+1}')])
    frames.append(frame)
    

sliders=[dict(steps= [dict(method= 'animate',
                           args= [[ f'{k+1}'],
                                  dict(mode= 'e',
                                  frame= dict( duration=1000, redraw= True ),
                                           transition=dict( duration= 0)
                                          )
                                    ],
                            label=f'{k+1}'
                             ) for k in range(np.shape(MC1Array[:,:,:])[0])],
                transition= dict(duration= 30 ),
                x=0,#slider starting position  
                y=0, 
                currentvalue=dict(font=dict(size=12), 
                                  prefix='Day: ', 
                                  visible=True, 
                                  xanchor= 'center'
                                 ),  
                len=1.0,
                active=1) #slider length)
           ]


# Update the plot with the frames
fig.update(frames=frames)

fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)

fig.update_scenes(xaxis_visible=False, yaxis_visible=False,zaxis_visible=False )

fig.show()
```

I tried to define the animation based on traces and on frames but both didn't work.